# Microdata itemprop on form inputs?

Tags: forms, html, microdata

I've been learning about HTML5 microdata, and I want to experiment with using them in my app. My app happens to ALWAYS display data as a form. From what I can tell by reading the spec on microdata, it seems that it isn't meant for use with HTML form inputs, is that true?

For example, would the following attributes be valid on an `input` element:

```
<input itemprop="fn" type="text" value="Oliver Twist">
```

I would expect that parsers would want to grab the value attribute of the input field... but it seems that this is not a valid case.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that appears to be correct. While the itemprop attribute is perfectly valid on `input` elements, the property value is the textContent of the element, which, since `input` is a void element, will always be the empty string.

Comment: Any insights from the W3C on WHY it doesn't seem to be designed to work on form inputs?

Comment: Not really. It's possibly felt that the semantics of the document shouldn't be dependent on user input, but I've no particular evidence to support or refute that.

Comment: Seems silly I know o many applications that respond to GETs with pre filled forms. Not to mention semantics are all about machine understanding, so putting this on forms would make it possible to implement a client that can understand how to query AND modify data.

Answer (score 1):

Microdata is meant to make it easier for other developers to scrape the data from your site to reuse it in other applications. For example, marking up your content with microdata makes it easier for Google to process your data and show it in Rich Snippets.

It isn't meant to interact with form processing at all, that's not part of the use case.

Comment: I get that. But I disagree that it isn't a valid use case. I've had the desire to make an interactive application that shows the current state of data always as editable views. Why not allow that to be scraped or processed by machines?

Comment: Another thing is that, I don't think allowing this would harm anything. Unless I'm wrong, it would only Add to the usefulness of microdata.